# Common Lisp: How to include a URL as an element of a list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to create a list that contains a URL, like this:

```
(setf assertion '(BookStore targetNamespace http://www.books.org))
```

But that results in this error message:

```
Error in READ [or a callee]: There is no package with the name HTTP.
```

Why does the URL produce an error?

How do I include a URL as an element of a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `http://www.books.org` tries to find the [`symbol`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_symbol.htm) `//www.books.org` in the [`package`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_pkg.htm) `http`. For more information about packages, you can read the chapter in [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html).

You should just add the item to the list as a string.

Comment: "the function" should probably be "the symbol".

Answer (score 5):

Do not use symbols as strings, it's not a good idea. Just use strings.

```
(defvar *assertion* (list "BookStore" "targetNamespace" "http://www.books.org"))
```

The URL produce an error because : is for accessing symbols in specified packages, like it says to you. So you just telling the compiler to find symbol "//www.books.org" in the package named "http", and there is no package with this name.